# CLion - Changing the default build directory

Tags: intellij-idea, cmake, clion

I've been having issues with changing the build directory via CLion. I've tried:
`set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "bin")` but it does not seem to change and remains the same (`/home/adil/.clion10/system/cmake/generated/c05c962b/c05c962b/Debug/Project`).
I have also tried the workaround specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25836027/where-clion-stores-executable-files), but that too does not seem to work.

Does anyone have a solution for this problem?

Comment: Also having this problem with build CL-138.2344.17 on Mac.

Comment: I have this problem too, but no solution below is acceptable.  Changing CMakeLists.txt is a silly idea since this is a versioned file.  Per-user configuration like the build directory should never go into the original sources and back upstream.

Comment: @srking what about using CMake environmental variable set per-user when invoking cmake, for example: `cmake -DVARIABLE=value`

Comment: I might uninstall Clion, this problem is so annoying

Comment: Pretty explained reply, check it out http://stackoverflow.com/a/28200869/1581505

Comment: @dktcup's link elaborates on... http://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2014/09/clion-answers-frequently-asked-questions/

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You need to prefix your `bin` with the path to the current directory your project resides in. You can use `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}`

```
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin")
```

Be sure to add this *before* related `add_executable` directive(s) in your CMakeLists.txt file.

Comment: or `set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib")` in case of library

Answer (score 13):

Go to Settings -> CMake and specify relative or absolute pass where you would like your build files to be stored in 'Build output path' field. For instance ./bin will output build files in YourProject/bin/Debug/yourExeFile.exe

[image]

Comment: Dmitry Kozhevnikov from JetBrains said: *it's called "Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | CMake | Build Directory" since 2020.2.* --- [Ability to specify the build/generation output directory : CPP-3374](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-3374/Ability-to-specify-the-buildgeneration-output-directory#focus=Comments-27-4590124.0-0)

Answer (score 4):

The wiped's answer is correct, just I must be add that you have to put that `set` directive before the `add_executable` directive, and before the `set` directive where the source files are defined for the `add_executable`, if you don't do in this way, the output will be the same and no errors will launched.

Comment: exactly... can't get why they downvote you... you saved my day! thank you

Comment: This is downvoted because it's clearly a comment to another answer. This should be added there, not as separate answer.

Comment: I just added Mrdev's qualification to @wiped's answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use *set_target_properties* :

```
set_target_properties( YOUR_PROJECT PROPERTIES RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "YOUR_BUILD_DIRECTORY")
```